# Merge DataFrames based on index columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I can see that what I'm trying to do is possible via `concat`: [Merge dataframes on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923880/merge-dataframes-on-index)

Why can I not do something equivalent using `merge`?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['joe strummer','johnny rotten'],'age':[73,80]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['nancy','sid'],'age':[17,19]})

df.index.name = 'x'
df2.index.name = 'y'

pd.merge(df2,df, left_on='y',right_on='x')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible; just use `left_index=True` instead of `left_on`, and `right_index=True` instead of `right_on`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
   age_x         name_x  age_y name_y
0     73   joe strummer     17  nancy
1     80  johnny rotten     19    sid
```

Using `left_on` doesn't work because indexes are separate objects to DataFrame columns. An index can have name, even an identical name to one of your columns, but `left_on` won't see it because it only looks at column names.

The [documentation for merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) gives the following guidance for these arguments:

> **left_index** : *boolean, default False*
>
> Use the index from the left DataFrame as the join key(s). If it is a MultiIndex, the number of keys in the other DataFrame (either the index or a number of columns) must match the number of levels

Comment: thanks - I should have looked at the specification a little closer! coming from a pure database background I'm finding pandas fascinating but not too intuitive.

Comment: No problem - I appreciate the fact that pandas' indexes are a little different to say, indexes in MySQL. It's a fantastic library when you get used to the differences though.

Comment: totally off subject but could I please pick your brains - if our db at work is sql-server will it be easy for me to move data between pandas and that db?

Comment: That's not an area I have very much experience with, unfortunately. pandas has various builtin methods for writing to and reading from SQL databases but I don't know if all versions/editions of sql-server are covered.